# Error message on javascript after publishing azure website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I have a problem here whenever I debug my appication on localhost, it runs perfectly with no errors on the brower, but when I publish it on azure I get an error on the browser.

Here is the error i get:

```
  /Service_Bind?depart_id=1:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded 
   with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my source code on the view page for javascript:

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#depart').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#Service').empty();
        $.get('Service_Bind', { depart_id: id }, function (data) {

            var v = '<option>---Select---</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                v += '<option value=' + v1.Value + '>' + v1.Text + '</option>';

            });
            $('#Service').html(v).text();
        });
    });








    $('#Gender').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#Item').empty();
        $.get('Item_Bind', { Gender_id: id }, function (data) {
            var v = '<option>---Select---</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                v += '<option value=' + v1.Value + '>' + v1.Text + '</option>';
            });
            $("#Item").html(v);
        });
    });



    $('#Item').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#price').empty();
        $.get('Price_Bind', { Price_id: id }, function (data) {
            var v = '<option>---Select---</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                v += '<option value=' + v1.Value + '>' + v1.Text + 
        '</option>';
            });
            $('#price').html(v);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: 404 means the URL is not valid.  Fix the relative URL properly

Comment: I would be lying if i say i do understand. I'm lost. So you mean I should check my url on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was suppose to add on the script and it worked. The only problem was to fetch a page so the browser didn't know where was it fetching. Thanks for your help.

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("Gender_Bind", "Request")', { Service_id: id }, function (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `$.get('Service_Bind', { depart_id: id }, function (data)` you are trying to call the api/method service_bind but you are not specifying the full url of that api.You need to add baseaddress as well.
For eg, my api is hosted on site www.contoso.com,then my url would be `www.constoso.com/Service_Bind`

Comment: It throws an error still, I have tried using all of these url: (http://skizo.azurewebsites.net/Service_Bind)
(https://skizo.azurewebsites.net/Service_Bind)
(/skizo.azurewebsites.net/Service_Bind)
(skizo.azurewebsites.net/Service_Bind) @VishalKhatal

Comment: Can you pls share code snippet and error you are getting after changing the URL? Looks like you are missing something.